# What credentials I need to be able to connect to Workday via Api

Tags: java, api, workday-api

I need to integrate with Workday API, but from a search all over the internet I didn't find any sure answer about what credentials I need to be able to connect .
as far as i find it's only user name and password butI saw something about Tenent and namespace?

does anyone know? can help me to understand? 
Thanks!
Tom

Answer (score 2):

Workday allows for multiple methods of authentication.

You can authenticate via WS-Security when interacting with Workday's native SOAP web services. You can find the WSDLs [here](https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/index.html) to generate a request more easily via  tool like SOAPui. For WSDLs, your authentication will be username@tenantname and password.

You can also authenticate to Reports as a Service (RaaS) via basic authentication through a REST request. Typically the authentication string is palced in the header and bae64 encoded. You do not need to include the @tenant name in authorization for REST requests. Basic authentication in a REST request can be achieved through an Authorization header like the following:

```
Authorization: base64Encoded(username:password)
```

If you are interested in more secure forms of authentication, Workday does provide the ability to register an API client within the tenant (search "Register API Client" inside your tenant). This allows you to further secure your connections to workday by encapsulating user authentication through OAuth2.0 or other authentication methods.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need your username, tenant name, and password to authenticate. For example, if my Workday username is **ab123456** and my tenant name is **thiscompanyinc**, I'll need to authenticate as **ab123456@thiscompanyinc**.

The password provided will be the same that you use for ab123456.

Namespace will not come into play during credentials and authentication. I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi first - Thank you for your answer!
Is there any place i can see how to "find" my tenant name? I want to find some graphical explanation about how can i create specific user for integration as I don't want to give my admin credentials for integrate.

Comment: @TomKetter your tenant name is the part of the path directly following "ccx/service/" in your endpoint's URL. Quick example using the tenant from above: https://wd2-impl-services1.workday.com/ccx/service/thiscompanyinc/Human_Resources/v32.0?wsdl

Comment: also, you're right on. do not use your personal credentials for automation. rather, explore leveraging Integration System Users (ISU). hope this gets you on the right track!

Comment: Thank you very much! you helped a lot.! 
do you have an example of an authentication xml? or soup request? please! and thank you again!